# set a default value for in xml for selection field odoo

Tags: xml, odoo

how set a default value for in xml for selection field odoo.

ttype = fields.Selection([('normal', 'Normal'),('counter','Counter'), ('exectuve', 'Executive')], default='normal', string='Type')

in xml

we can default value from **python** using **default keyword** default=True . but instaed of that i want to make it in xml.. how to it

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the context in act window too in order to set the default values.